# can cron messages display images?

Tags: cron

Very simple question - when I run a cron job, everything echoed gets caught and sent to me as a server notification email (not sure exactly what you'd call it). I was wondering if the format for these supports images?

Of course I could just send an email at the end of the cron with my image attached, but I'm curious as to the syntax and format of these server messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the cron job is simply packaged up into a mail and sent to the relevant address.

So there's nothing stopping you from (for example) uuencoding an image and pushing that out to standard output, in the right format so that it shows up as an attachment at the destination.

Comment: Perhaps this could be elaborated slightly.  Traditional email messages are `Content-Type: text/plain` and do not support images.  The default message sent by Cron is pretty much forced to use this content type. However, if your script formats and sends an email message on its own, it's free to use the full palette of MIME, for example `Content-Type: multipart/related` with a main body part with `Content-Type: text/html` which in turn refers to other body parts which are images.  This comment box is not a good place to demonstrate this programmatically, but examples should be easy to find.

Comment: Of course, for a message which is only sent to consenting adults, plain old text messages with `uuencode` attachments in the text itself are probably acceptable, albeit clunky.  These days, regular users would expect a properly formatted MIME message.